# Concatenate rows in one table as one column in different table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, group-concat

I think fundamentally, I am not understanding how to accomplish joining 2 tables together using a related table, I need help.

1. I have one table called 'formoptionslist' it has 3 columns (id, name, active)
2. A relate table called 'formoptionslistformoptionsrelates' it has 3 columns(id, formoptionslist_id, formoptions_id)
3. and finally a 'formoptions' table that has 3 columns (id, name, value)

Table values are loosely represented as the following:

formoptionslist

```
id |   name   | active
---------------------
1  | statuses | 1
```

formoptionslistformoptionsrelates

```
id | formoptionslist_id | formoptions_id
------------------------------------
1  | 1                  | 1    
2  | 1                  | 2   
3  | 1                  | 3
```

formoptions

```
id | name                   | value
------------------------------------
1  | Successfully Purchased | success    
2  | Shipping Error         | shipping_error   
3  | Failed Payment         | failed_payment
```

What I am trying to build is the following in one query.

```
[{name: statues, 
     options:[
         {name: 'Successfully Purchased', value: 'success'},
         {name: 'Shipping Error, value: 'shipping_error'},
         {name: 'Failed Payment', value: 'failed_payment'}
     ]
}]
```

I using php and PDO to query mysql

What I have been able to do is generate something like:

```
[{"options":"1,2,3,"}]
```

using the following test query ( I'm just trying to understand the SQL at this point, no need to comment about how I am not using placeholders, etc.

```php
$this->db->select(
    'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT formoptions_id) as options'.self::from.self::formoptionslistformoptionsrelates
        .self::leftJoin.self::formoptions
        .self::on
        .self::formoptionslistformoptionsrelates.'.formoptions_id'
        .self::equals.self::formoptionslistformoptionsrelates.'.formoptions_id'
    .self::where.'formoptionslist_id = 1'
    .' GROUP BY formoptionslist_id'
);
```

The above prints out to the following:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT formoptions_id) as options 
FROM formoptionslistformoptionsrelates 
LEFT JOIN _formoptions ON formoptionslistformoptionsrelates.formoptions_id = formoptionslistformoptionsrelates.formoptions_id 
WHERE formoptionslist_id = 1 
GROUP BY formoptionslist_id
```

I know that fundamentally, what I am trying to accomplish is possible. But I am not sure how to get there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is all that `self::XXX` stuff in the SQL?

Comment: You can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to create a JSON array from the results of a query. This is much better than trying to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to create the JSON as a string.

Comment: And `JSON_OBJECT()` to create JSON object notation.

Comment: Although generating json output straight within a relational database is probably not the best idea. I would return a traditional tabular result via sql and do the transformation in the php code.

Comment: @Barmar, the ```self::xxx``` is just a way of holding values like table names, etc in constants in php. I've used JSON_ARRAYAGG, but it is still not returning the desired output.

Comment: @Shadow, why would you recommend that approach as opposed to using Barmar's approach below?

Comment: @Willie you are wasting the database layer's resources on formatting the data and strictly speaking it does not return the results you want as you get a tabular result with json object in each row. If you want hierarchical json outputs from a database, then use a nosql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON_OBJECT` to create the objects, and `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to combine the value within a group into an array.

Then join all 3 tables.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
        'name', l.name,
        'options', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'name', o.name,
                'value', o.value
            )
        )
    ) AS result
FROM formoptionslist AS l
LEFT JOIN formoptionslistformoptionsrelates AS ol ON l.id = ol.formoptionslist_id
LEFT JOIN formoptions AS o ON o.id = formoptions_id
WHERE l.id = 1
GROUP BY l.id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shnrSDxSzxGMWUYYgYgBnT/1)

Comment: Ok, that for sure worked. I am going to add it as part of my larger query to see what the functionality does then post back.